# Procedure for explicit type conversion in python from a float to int

Tags: python

I am composing a program which allows me to calculate a person's age in days- accounting for every day including leap days, and irregular number of days in months. 
Here is a line of code:

```
number_of_days = (((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1)
```

I got the value `30.4375` by dividing `365.25` by `12`.

Now I only need to store the integer part in `number_of_days`. How do I do that?

Help is really appreciated!

P.S. All variable values are int values

Comment: The correct answer is to use a cast to int().  However, when you attempt this, you are getting an error as though you are attempting to assign a value to the int() function.  Show us more of the surrounding code (when you try int()), and we'll find your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider to use round instead of converting that is more accurate:

```
import math
int(math.round((((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1)))
```

Comment: That is very specific to the intention of the application.  If I am 25 years and 300 days old, I don't say that I am 26 years old.  I say that I am 25 (even though rounding would lead me to 26).

Comment: Hey! Thats a great idea! But would it return an int value?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I say I am 28 when I am 27 and 8 months old

Comment: @AbrarKhan yes there is `int(expression)`

Comment: @0x90 I stand corrected!  That's what I get for making assumptions about everyone else!

Comment: @BlackVegetable you are OK the problem is with me trying to be older :)

Comment: Hey yeah! It prints int values now :) Thanks sooo much Guys! I sincerely thank you all :)

Answer (score 4):

You can either use `int`:

```
number_of_days = int((((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1))
```

or `math.floor`:

```
import math

number_of_days = math.floor((((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1))
```

But then `number_of_days` will be a `float`, so I think the first solution is better.

Comment: Thats great! But only the integer part in required. Floor function is returning a float value.
Also the second method doesn't seem to work it is giving an error of invalid syntax.

Comment: yup- its giving an error of invalid syntax- I apologize in advance if I have done something silly; I am learning python at the moment: The error returned is: 

  int:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Show us what you are doing that is resulting in the syntax error.

Comment: This should be: 
number_of_days = int((((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1))

Comment: Thanks soo much everyone! You guys helped me out!

Answer (score 3):

Just call `int`:

```
number_of_days = int((((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1))
```

Comment: @AbrarKhan Print more of your code, your syntax sounds like it is having trouble.

Comment: Hey! Thanks so much! Fixed it. I sincerely thank you for great advice thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Could you just use the floor function?

```
number_of_days = math.floor((((year2 - year1) * 12) + (month2 - month1)) * 30.4375 + (day2 - day1))
```

Comment: math.floor will store it as 30.0, which can be irritating.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to calculate the number of days between dates you can use the datetime module:

```
import datetime
birth = datetime.date(1967,11,14)
today = datetime.date.today()

number_of_days = (today - birth).days
```